# Why is "ls -a" giving me an error in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, git-bash

I’m following a video and the instructor needed to show list of folder contents and he typed `ls –a` on VS Code's terminal which showed a list of the folder contents.

But when I typed same the same command on my VS Code, I got an error:

> Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 'a' is ambiguous. Possible matches include: -Attributes -Directory -File -Hidden

Then I went to Git Bash and typed the same command, and it gave me the exact result I needed (which is the list of my folder contents).

Why is the same command working well in Git Bash but giving an error in VS Code?

The command I'm trying to execute:

```
ls -a
```

Result on Git Bash (which is correct):

```
./   .eslintcache  .gitignore     package.json       public/    src/
../  .git/         node_modules/  package-lock.json  README.md
```

Comment: That error message comes from PowerShell, which is an entirely different shell so it has its own commands. In particular, PowerShell has an `ls` command too, but it has different arguments.

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing your default terminal is not "bash":

[image]

You can change your default terminal by pressing F1 in VS Code and typing "Terminal: Select Default Shell".

[image]

Select that and then you can select "Git Bash" from this dropdown. Now go back to your integrated terminal and try to execute the command.

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Josh Stevens, I followed your instruction and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

`ls -a` is a command for listing files on Unix/Linux-based systems.

Git Bash uses bash as its shell so Unix/Linux commands work on it.

You need to either enter `dir` as the equivalent command in Windows, or change your default shell to bash in VS Code.

Answer (score -1):

In Linux we have ls command
but in cmd on windows doesn't support ls or some of the linux command
so alternative is to use
dir
Or you can switch between the terminal as Josh suggested and use Powershell or Git Bash.