# ls -a is not working on the Terminal of Visual Studio Code. I am trying to use Git - GitHub and to list all hidden files in VS Code terminal

Tags: github

`ls -a` is not working on the Terminal of Visual Studio Code. I am trying to use Git to list all hidden files.

```
Get-ChildItem : Parameter cannot be processed because the 
parameter name 'a' is ambiguous. Possible matches include:     
-Attributes -Directory -File -Hidden -ReadOnly -System.        
At line:1 char:4
+ ls -a
+    ~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameter,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Also when using powershell `ls -a` is not working. I am getting a same error message.

Comment: It's not working and you're getting the same error because in both cases _you're using powershell_. So look up the relevant info - read e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/73207344/3001761.

Comment: `ls` is a Unix coreutil. It's not standard PowerShell. PowerShell (un)helpfully [aliases it to `Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/shell/using-aliases?view=powershell-7.4), which has different syntax and behavior.

Comment: All this command don't work: 

dir ./d
dir /a
dir ./a
dir /ad
dir \h

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the cmd line equivalent of "ls -a" in Powershell on Windows Vscode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73207344/whats-the-cmd-line-equivalent-of-ls-a-in-powershell-on-windows-vscode)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is "ls -a" giving me error in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65377840/why-is-ls-a-giving-me-error-in-vs-code)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are on powershell, i would recommend that you install `git-bash` for windows and run the unix commands that you want to use (for eg `ls -a`)

Comment: git version 2.43.0.windows.1 is installed, still command ls -a not working

Comment: I am referring to "git bash" which is an installable that's different from "git". Please see the formatting that i had done specifically to avoid such a mis-interpretation

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to switch Visual studio terminal to Git bash.
At a top right corner of the terminal click at the down arrow which is located near a '+' down button. Then select Git Bash instead of the Power Shell

Comment: This might be a reasonable suggestion, but it doesn’t answer their question about how to do this in Visual Studio Code. It would be better suited as a comment.